# update と upgrade に使い分けはありますか？

Tags: 専門用語, 英語

ライブラリ管理などの似たような言葉に、 update と upgrade があります。

## 質問

- それぞれを使い分けるにあたっての基準は、プログラミング的に何かあったりしますでしょうか？

  - (ない場合、それはつまりそれぞれのライブラリ・管理ツールが思い思いの方を用語として採用している、ということでしょうか？)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっくりとは以下のような認識です。

**アップデート**
ソフトウェアバージョンの「更新」

**アップグレード**
ソフトウェア/ハードウェアの「拡張」

---

**例1**
Windowsのパッチはアップデート。メジャーバージョンの変更を伴う更新 (7 -> 10など) はアップグレード。

**例2**
Debina/Ubuntu の `apt` コマンドで `apt update` はパッケージ情報の更新、`apt upgrade`, `apt dist-upgrade` がパッケージの更新。

**参考:**
[アップデートとアップグレードの違い](https://www.siraberu-tool.net/difference/157.php)

> アップグレードとは
> アップグレードも英語にしてみるとよくわかります。 「up(アップ)」「grade(グレード)」を組み合わせた単語です。「grade」は「等級」「階級」という意味の単語で、「アップグレード」は等級やランクをあげることを指します。

Comment: なるほど、その感じでいくと、ライブラリ管理ツールにおいては、 update 的側面 (patch) と upgrade 的側面 (major) があって、どっちを選ぶかは、ツール作成者の哲学による、ということになりそう